# Need a function to verify if a password is strong

Tags: haskell

I need to create a function to verify if a password is strong. If have more then 8 characters, at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase and 1 digit. But my function doesn't work. What could be wrong?

```
forte :: String -> Bool

forte s = if (length n >= 8) && (isLower s /= 0) && (isUpper s /= 0) && (isDigit s /= 0)
          then True
          else False
```

Comment: you seem to be assuming that eg. `isLower s` returns the number of lower-case characters in `s`. In fact the function applies to a single character and returns a `Bool` telling you if that character is lowercase. There are a number of fixes but the most concise involves the function [any](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any)

Comment: What's wrong? Please be clear. And why are you checking those predicates results against 0?

Comment: If you have something that "doesn't work" you should include a description of _how_ it doesn't do what you expect. In this case it's clear enough that your code won't typecheck but it won't be obvious in all circumstances. (Side note: password policies like this are a pretty terrible idea, I hope you're doing this for fun and not for real production software)

Comment: Try narrowing it down in a repl. For example, does `isLower "Foo"` return 2 the way you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.  In the future please be specific when you say something "does not work".  Copying and pasting the error message is a great start.

For your case there are a few issues.

1. There is no variable `n`. I think you mean `s` as in `length s`.
2. The `isLower` function operates on characters, not strings (lists of characters).  You should check the length of the filtered list (`length (filter isLower s) /= 0`).  Same goes for `isUpper` and `isDigit`.
3. Incidentally, the `if` statement is entirely unneeded.  Any time you write `if expr then True else False` it is the same as just writing `expr`.

Applying these suggestions we have:

```
forte s = (length s >= 8) && (length (filter isLower s) /= 0) && (length (filter isUpper s) /= 0) && (length (filter isDigit s) /= 0)
```

or with a helper function:

```
forte s = (length s >= 8) && (cnt isLower /= 0) &&
          (cnt isUpper /= 0) && (cnt isDigit /= 0)
  where cnt p = length (filter p s)
```

But I would probably write it as (typed but not tested):

```
forte s = and [ length s >= 8
              , cnt isLower /= 0
              , cnt isUpper /= 0
              , cnt isDigit /= 0]
  where cnt p = length (filter p s)
```

EDIT: Ah, and I don't know why I didn't consider any instead of counting elements.  Thanks to @lorenzo

```
forte s = and [ length s >= 8
              , any isLower s
              , any isUpper s
              , any isDigit s]
```

Or with all and any, though this requires you to understand the partial application of `$` and function composition (`.`):

```
forte s = all ($ s) [ (>= 8) . length
                    , any isLower
                    , any isUpper
                    , any isDigit ]
```

Comment: You could also use the `any` function which i believe is more readable in this case

Comment: The `all` solution, much like `any`, is sort of odd looking to beginners because the partially applied function application operator `f s = all ($ s) [(>= 8) . length, has isLower, has isUpper, has isDigit] where has p = not . null . filter p`.  I'd upvote a reasonable alternative, code golf-esque, answer.

Comment: I believe they meant that `any isLower s` should be used instead of `length (filter isLower s) /= 0`